# disco#items is returning error code 403

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, service-discovery

I am trying to get list of all the users registered on the server. My server is Ejabberd. When I use service discovery on `all users` node, I get 403 error. Here's my request stanza and error stanza -

**Request**

```
<iq id="U7" type="get" to="server.lt" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <query node="all user" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" />
</iq>
```

**Response**

```
<iq from="server.lt" to="user@server.lt/res" id="U8" type="error" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="all users" />
  <error code="403" type="auth">
    <forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
  </error>
</iq>
```

When I checked on server, I didn't find any mod_disco there, so I added new mod_disco module. Do I need to do further modification on server or is there any problem in my request stanza?

**Update:**
I tried by giving my user admin access and the command did work, but it's not practical to give each user an admin access. Is there any way I can do it using client or the server without using admin access for user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the `all users` info node is hard-coded to use the `configure` access rule.  In the default configuration, it's set to only allow server admins:

```
%% Only admins can use the configuration interface:
{access, configure, [{allow, admin}]}.
```

There is no way to configure ejabberd to give access to just `all users` without giving access to configure everything else, it's all or nothing.  You'd have to change the source code to achieve what you want.

Comment: I suppose I'll need to give all users access then. How can I do that? SHould I replace admin with user?

Comment: If you have a declaration like `{acl, user, ....}`, you could do that.  The default configuration includes a `local` ACL, so you could change the above to `{access, configure, [{allow, local}]}`.  Note that that would give all local users permission to create and delete users and change other users' passwords.

Comment: Thanks for this. The server is for private use anyways. I actually don't have access to ejabberd config file, is there any way this could be done using the web admin panel instead? It does have mod_adhoc and mod_configure module in it.

Comment: It was a while since I used it, but I seem to remember that the web admin panel lets you modify access rules somewhere…